# Is there a tabbed view for VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Just wondering if there is a way to get a tabbed view in VS Code (editor), and if not, is that feature yet to be added?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**

Yes! VS Code 1.3.0 added this feature.

**Original**

Not as of v0.3.0, as far as I know.

Feature requests: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code

Issue reporting: https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List

Comment: Direct link to the feature request: [UserVoice: "Implement Tabs"](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/293070-visual-studio-code/suggestions/7752519-implement-tabs)

Comment: It seems that the implementation of this feature has begun

Comment: Any idea whats the shortcut for switching tabs?

Comment: Ctrl+tab works on Mac. Not sure if the same works in other platforms.

Answer (score 15):

Yes to both of your questions.

It recently became available, if you are on the nightly Insiders release.  This will soon be introduced into the product itself as well, most likely in early July.

- First, download the [Insiders release.](http://code.visualstudio.com/insiders)
- In VS Code Insider's top application menu, open Preferences >
  User Settings, and then add the following setting `"workbench.editor.showTabs": true`

You then will have tabs enabled in your editor as shown below

[image: VS Code with tabs enabled]

Comment: Thank God! Insiders release does have this setting! Although key has slightly changed: `workbench.editor.showTabs`

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to the tabs concept tha i found is using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate in the history of opened files.

Comment: An even closer thing: double click a file and it goes to "Working Files" above the rest of your projects, and that works almost like tabs would.

Answer (score 0):

VS Code v1.3.0 has tabs similar to that of sublime text.

But Tab switching is still the same as the previous version.

[image]